# Equipped for sailing

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]
[Grid in plaintext](https://pastebin.com/69BTV1ZL)

**Across**
1/13/20. State of Colorado engaged in attempt to pursue mostly American parties, often involving heroin (10,8,2,3,5)
10. "Terminal engineer, too, must… (7)
11. …ultimately possess baby's bed", express fringe writers (7)
12. Exhume and mount decayed body's head (6)
13. *(See 1 across)*
14. American refined fuel near Scottish loch produces value (10)
16. An island or small, crooked key (4)
19. Rock group's principle of keeping things simple (4)
20. *(See 1 across)*
23. Heavy snowfall as ribald comic catches some z's (8)
26. Maybe Cupid's bow is in front of her? (6)
28. Big mule worked for 1/13/20 across colonizer (7)
29. Italian city attempts to evacuate leaders (7)
30. Equipped for sailing? Go canoeing, maybe? (5-5)

**Down**
2. Giant mouse hybrid accepts no resistance (8)
3. Promise of tango finale at hotel (4)
4. Lists of exotic resorts (7)
5. Baltic city's pastry with unsweetened topping (5)
6. Corrupting leader, Ba'al desecrated clandestine organization (5)
7. 1/13/20 across dictator's gang decapitated Hutu (6)
8. On the contrary, Mr. Eliot says (or stammers) (8)
9. Somewhat tipsy, cherub becomes Cupid's lover (6)
15. Consume animal product, omitting the head (3)
17. Clan's home taken initially as a capital (8)
18. Almost twenty-four pioneer leaders describe small animal (8)
19. Meat dishes from 16 across evenly placed before Barbara (6)
21. Superior boxer who famously fought in 17 down (7)
22. Conan's running to get French cheese (6)
24. Bigwig looking to keep a place to live (5)
25. Once 1/13/20 across's name for reformed Azeri (5)
27. African footballer – and European, as well (4)

Comment: Once again, another great cryptic! I loved 4D for its simplicity and distractingness.  26A, 29A, and 24D were also nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]
>  (The explanation for the first clue has parts bolded and colored to indicate correspondences. The break in the wordplay is not related to the break in the clue; both are only there to save space, and do not happen at the same place in the clue.)

Comment: Another impressively quick solve, four weeks in a row now! I had something else in mind for 27d, though.

Comment: @jafe I'm guessing it's "Eto'o": "European" -> E, "as well" -> too

Comment: @oAlt Yep, that's it!

Comment: Ah, I wasn't familiar with either the abbreviation or the player - will fix!